# Does `titleps` conflict with `babel`?

Tags: titleps, babel-french

The word "french" comes just before the chapter heading. Is that a bug, and is there a fix?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % due to warning from babel
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titleps}

%http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titleps.pdf#section.1
\newpagestyle{main}{\sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][(\thesection]  % even
  {\thesection)}{\sectiontitle}{\thepage}} % odd
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Intro}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: Shot1]

Comment: I have no problem with this code. B.t.w. the language option of babel should be loaded with the document class. Check your code – there might be a forgotten ‘french’ somewhere.

Comment: "I have no problem with this code.": are you being passive-aggressive with me?!

Comment: @Erwann As the code works for Bernard you should show your log file so that one can check for differences.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/2Z6ky1jV) it is.

Comment: @Bernard I can reproduce the issue using an uptodate TeXLive 2019 or an uptodate MiKTeX. But it works for me, if  I switch to TeXLive 2018.

Comment: @esdd: I don't understand. I have a perfecty up-to-date MiKTeX installation and I can't reproduce the problem. Did you use this very code?

Comment: @Bernard yes, I have used the code in the question: [Result](https://www.svb-stutensee.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/LaTeX1.pdf) Only `\listfiles` was added: [log file](https://www.svb-stutensee.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/LaTeX1.txt).

Comment: Very strange…We use the same versions of packages, the only difference is the distribution.

Comment: @Erwann The log you have linked doesn't correspond to the posted MWE (it loads `titlesec`). It works for me, too, I'm trying to guess what's going on.

Comment: @JavierBezos I can reproduce the problem, and it quite obviously is related to the fact that \markboth is robust now. But I don't quite get what titleps is doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\markboth is a robust command now, and the code of titleps seems not to handle this correctly. A possible work-around for now seems to be this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{titleps}
\makeatletter
\def\ttl@mb@mark{\csname markboth \endcsname} % patch
\makeatother
\newpagestyle{main}{}
\pagestyle{main}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ulrike. I didn't expect it to be a change in the LaTeX kernel (maybe that's why I didn't find where the problem was). I'll fix it and in a few days I'll upload a new version.